# Find $\int(\frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x^2}+\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{x})dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**Problem:** Find
$$\int\left(\frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x^2}+\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{x}\right)dx$$

The possible methods I thought were:

1. Substitute $t=\tan{\left({x\over2}\right)}$: failed because of polynomials in the denominators
2. Put $t={\pi\over2}-x$: failed because of polynomials in the denominators
3. Substitute $t=\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{x}$: failed - it is difficult to express $\frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x^2}$ in terms of $t$.
4. Partial integration: but I couldn't find the way to split into $f'$ and $g$.
5. Using $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sqrt{2}\sin\left({x+{\pi\over4}}\right)$ and $\cos{x}-\sin{x}=\sqrt{2}\sin\left({x-{\pi\over4}}\right)$, but failed since I also don't know how to integral $\int\frac{\sin\left({x+{\pi\over4}}\right)}{x^2}$ and $\int\frac{\sin\left({x-{\pi\over4}}\right)}{x}$.

I wanted to focus on the fact that
$$\cos{x}-\sin{x}=\left(\sin{x}+\cos{x}\right)'$$ 
but it also did not work well.

Is there a special idea to solve these types of integrals - when the fraction includes polynomials in the denominator and trigonometry functions in the numerator? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this integral requires nonelementary functions, such as $\text{Si}(x)$; there is no elementary way to describe it.

In case you accidentally missed a minus sign when transcribing your integral, observe that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{x} = -\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{x^2} + \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{x}.$$

Comment: Ah, then it has the possibility that the problem has a typo in my prints. Thanks!

Comment: So considering the alternate question, would the best way be by-part? Or something else entirely?

Comment: The alternate question is solved by the derivative mentioned in the answer, and FTC.

Comment: Isn't $-\frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x^2}$ in the derivation part?

Comment: @ToBY Ah, my bad, I made a typo. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @hdighfan Whatever, thanks very much sir :D